# filter is acting weird - angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, filter

I have two columns which are both used as item lists that I can add something into the list and also have a search to search what's in the list.
Somehow I realized that it's acting weird, if I input 1 in search, it'll show everything in column 1 but in column 2 it'll only show if a text contained 1 vise versa for column 2.  If I use any other texts other than 1/2 alone the filter works normally.

This is my html

```
<div class="row input-output-panel">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 left-column">
        <div class="input-item">
            <input type="text" placeholder="ENTER ITEM" ng-model="item.name" class="enter-item">

            <select class="column-select" ng-model="item.pos" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions">
            </select>

            <button class="add-button" type="button" ng-click="addItem(item)">Add Item</button>
        </div>

        <div class="search-item">
            <label for="search">Search An Item</label>
            <div class="search-input">
                <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="SEARCH" id="search"><span class="fa fa-search icon-search"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 item-columns column1">
        <table class="table-striped table-w-override">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="column-header">Column 1</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{ pos: 'column1' } | filter:query" ng-class-odd="odd" ng-class-even="even">
                    <td>{{item.name}}<span ng-click="remove(item)" class="remove-button fa fa-times"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 item-columns column2">
        <table class="table-striped table-w-override">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="column-header">Column 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{ pos: 'column2' } | filter:query" ng-class-odd="odd" ng-class-even="even">
                <td>{{item.name}}<span ng-click="remove(item)" class="remove-button fa fa-times"></span></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is nothing about filter is added into the script part.
Am I looking over the head and missed something again?

Thank you in advance for the one helped.

Comment: what is the behavior you are expecting ? and why are you using the same list of items for both columns ?

Comment: what is filter:{ pos: 'column2' } supposed to do ?

Comment: the items can be either added into column 1 or column 2 `filter:{ pos: 'column2' }` shows whatever is added into column 2